# Large number of Port forwarding in nginx

Tags: nginx, port, iptables, portforwarding

I'm trying to add mapping for 20K Ports (range [40k-60k]) in the nginx configuration.
This config is added to nginx.conf

```
stream{
    server {
        listen 40000;
        listen 40001;
        .
        .
        .
        listen 60000;
        proxy_pass <backend-url>:$server_port;
     }
}
```

Everything works jolly-good when number of mappings is < 500. But when it's increased to 20K mappings, the delay in response is tremendous. Any work-around or any other method to add port-forwarding?

Comment: related q and a: https://serverfault.com/q/279262/436331  https://serverfault.com/a/661366/436331

Answer (score 7):

Since Nginx 1.15.10 you can specify a range of ports on listen directive.

```
Port ranges (1.15.10) are specified with the first and last port separated by a hyphen:

listen 127.0.0.1:12345-12399;
listen 12345-12399;
```

More info: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html#listen

Comment: notice you should also set the resolver and server_port
`resolver 127.0.0.1; proxy_pass you_server_ip:$server_port;`

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to do accomplish it via `iptables` instead of `nginx`

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/

> You can easily redirect incoming traffic by inserting rules into
>   PREROUTING chain of the nat table. You can set destination port using
>   the REDIRECT target

i.e.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10000
```

and listen port 10000 in `nginx`

Related discussion: https://superuser.com/questions/440324/iptables-how-to-forward-all-external-ports-to-one-local-port